# How to bind <DrawingImage> from resource dictionary using MVVM and Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Help, please. I have an XAML image in ResourceDictionary `<DrawingImage x:Key="MyDrawingImage">`. How can I bind it to <ListBox.ItemTemplate> using MVVM? List Item has text and image.

```
public class MyItemViewModel {
    public string TextToDisplay { get; set; }
    
    public string? ImageToDisplay { get; set;}    ??????            
}
```

The question is, what is the most elegant way to bind an image from resource dictionary?

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border CornerRadius="10">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageToDisplay}" ???????? />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                                       Text="{Binding TextToDisplay}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found an answer. Maybe this will come in handy for someone:

```
public class DsItemViewModel {
    public DsItemViewModel(string name, string? drawingImageResourceKey = null) {
        Name = name;                
        if (drawingImageResourceKey != null)
            Image = Application.Current.FindResource(drawingImageResourceKey) as DrawingImage;
    }
    
    public string Name { get; }

    public DrawingImage? Image { get; }
}
```

Comment: Usually it is better to avoid having specific UI elements exposed by your view-model. 
 It gives you more flexibility to change it later.  So although your solution does work, it would probably be a better idea to keep this all in XAML.  You could have just changed your XAML `Image` to look like this: `<Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDrawingImage}}"/>`

Comment: I cannot write <Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyDrawingImage}}"/>, because I have reusable control, which diplays different list of images and labels in different places of my app.

Comment: I'm confused then.  Your question said that you wanted to bind that `Image` to  the resource  "MyDrawingImage*   The solution you presented does the same thing as what I suggested, except  in code behind.    

Or are you saying that you have multiple such `DrawingImage` objects in resources with multiple keys and the View-model might get any of them?

Comment: Yes, exact. I have multiple images in my resource dictionary, and I want to have single reusable control for different lists with different images and labels.

Comment: Ah, got it.    Makes sense then.